# Bandwidth of an EEG signal

Tags: python, fft, canopy

I'm trying to perform FFT of an EEG signal in Python, and then basing on the bandwidth determine whether it's alpha or beta signal. It looked fine, but the resulting plots are nothing like they should, the frequencies and magnitude values are not what I expected. Any help appreciated, here's the code:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
import scipy
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

eeg = loadmat("eeg_2013.mat");
eeg1=eeg['eeg1'][0]
eeg2=eeg['eeg2'][0]
fs = eeg['fs'][0][0]
fft1 = scipy.fft(eeg1)
f = np.linspace (fs,len(eeg1), len(eeg1), endpoint=False)
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot (f, abs (fft1))
plt.title ('Magnitude spectrum of the signal')
plt.xlabel ('Frequency (Hz)')
show()
plt.subplot(212)
fft2 = scipy.fft(eeg2)
f = np.linspace (fs,len(eeg2), len(eeg2), endpoint=False)
plt.plot (f, abs (fft2))
plt.title ('Magnitude spectrum of the signal')
plt.xlabel ('Frequency (Hz)')
show()
```

And the plots:
[image: img]

Comment: And, most importantly, I'm not sure how can I read bandwidth from this plots...

Comment: There is an underlying problem, and depends on the input data, or how they are normalized, because the EEG signals normally have a range of 10 to 50 Hz, your 1 to 9 kHz, which put the input signal? where you take it?

Comment: these two lines:
eeg1=eeg['eeg1'][0]
eeg2=eeg['eeg2'][0]

it is read from a .mat file, that stores variables

Comment: It might be helpful if you provided a link to your data.

Comment: the data looks like this:
http://oi40.tinypic.com/2u4srrm.jpg

Comment: Regarding the data plot, units would be helpful.

Comment: there are no units, it's a raw vector plot with subsequent values. the sampling frequency is fs = 200

Comment: You didn't specify units to go with your sampling frequency but, making the guess that the units are Hertz (i.e. 200 Hz), then, by the Nyquest theorem, you cannot resolve any frequency higher than 100 Hz.

Comment: okay, but the thing is, these two signals are EEG readings, one is alpha and the second is beta wave. and I am to determine their bandwidths, and on that basis say which one is which. any advice on achieving that? ;)

Comment: Seems like your FFT is shifted (0 is at approx 4500Hz in your plot). Use [fftfreq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html) to get the true frequencies.

Comment: thanks, no idea though how to use it... I'm a real, real morron in this field, talk to me like to a 3-year old child

Comment: So... what exactly is the question here? "Does not look like expected" is quite vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sampling frequency is `fs` and you have `N=len(eeg1)` samples, then the `fft` procedure will, of course, return an array of `N` values. The first `N/2` of them correspond to the frequency range `0..fs/2`, the second half of the frequency corresponds to the mirrored frequency range `-fs/2..0`. For real input signals the mirrored half is just the complex conjugate of the positive half, so it can be disregarded in further analysis (but not in the inverse fft).

So essentially, you should format

`f=linspace(0,N-1,N)*fs/N`

Edit: or even more simple with minimal changes to the inital code

`f = np.linspace (0,fs,len(eeg1), endpoint=False)`

so `f` ranges from `0` to just before `fs` and disregard the second half of the fft result in the output:

`plt.plot(  f(0:N/2), abs( fft1(0:N/2) )  )`

---

Added: You can use fftshift to exchange both halves, then the correct frequency range is

`f = np.linspace (-fs/2,fs/2,len(eeg1), endpoint=False)`

Answer (score 3):

In order to get an array of the fft frequencies, you should use [fftfreq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fftfreq.html); it gives you an array of frequencies to use as absciss:

```py
from scipy.fftpack import fftfreq

eeg = loadmat("eeg_2013.mat");
eeg1=eeg['eeg1'][0]
eeg2=eeg['eeg2'][0]
fs = eeg['fs'][0][0]
fft1 = scipy.fft(eeg1)
f=fftfreq(eeg1.size,1/fs)
```

Sorry, I can't test this code in real conditions because you didn't post a data sample, but I hope this should work.

Concerning how to determine the bandwidth, as far as I understand, you want to get the fundamental frequency. There are different ways, more or less complicated whether your signal is noisy or not, ... In your case, you only want to know if the fundamental frequency f0 is in the range 8-13Hz (alpha) or 13-30Hz (beta); one very simple way is to compute the maximum of the fft in the range 8-13Hz: `fft1[(f>8) & (f<13)].max()` and if it's more than, say, 1000, it's an alpha wave, otherwise it's beta. If your signals are less similar, please post some examples of different kinds of samples and the result you would have, so that we can try more complicated algorithms.